# Illustrator: how to determine whether all text in AI file is outlined or not

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, print-production, outline

I was working on a printable design for a client, before sending Ai file to the client I outlined all the fonts.

But the client told me that printing people having an issue with the missing font, I searched in the whole doc and an un-outlined font was not found.

Is there any universal way to find if there are any fonts used or not in the Ai document?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sometimes there are empty text objects which are invisible, locked or hidden, but can still get listed as text objects in the file. Use 'Type → Find Font' to see all the fonts in your document and where they are used.

Also to make sure everything is converted to outlines, select all and convert to outlines, which should leave you with an empty list in the 'Find Font' panel.

[image]

Comment: You are right, a font is found but how can i navigate to that font in the layer panel

Comment: There should be a Find button.

Comment: Thanks, find button was not working, as the file was hidden, but thanks issue solved